# Magento 2 configurable product not open

Tags: magento2

I migrate one of my client's website from Magento 1.7 to Magento 2.1. All products work properly but when I open configurable product from admin it will not open and give this kind of message.

[image]

And this message appears in system log

```
[2016-09-15 07:43:56] main.CRITICAL: Requested product doesn't exist [] []
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try expanding your question a little bit, provide a snapshot of the database, and more configuration options you have in place, it makes it easier to answer.

Comment: @aledustet I just edit one configurable product from admin side and it will display something like this which I gave in image and also give in system.log file one line which I added upon.

Thanks